# Allowing users to Utilize Remote Desktop Connection on their PC

Tags: windows, active-directory, azure, rdp, endpoint

Hi everybody i need help with this issue. So currently all users cannot connect in via RDP unless they are an administrator on their PC.I want to enable RDP access to all users , but Windows cannot properly resolve Azure AD groups.
Users need to be added to the Remote Desktop Users local group to be authorized for remoting in.I tried adding via Endpoint Security>Account Protection and i feel like the computer doesnt know how to read Azure AD Groups. Thanks everyone in advance

Comment: I had already a similar situation and fixed it by using the command line and using net group

Comment: can you explain with little details how u did that?thank you

Comment: `net localgroup administrators /add "AzureAD\UserUpn"` remind that you need the localized named for your country that the command works, this can also be used for the remote desktop group or similar. you need just to run net localgroup to see them